# UIPickerView that looks like UIDatePicker but with seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I am making a timer app and needed to display hour, min and seconds to the user. I tried using `UIDatePicker` but it shows only hours and mins as selections. Not seconds. After doing a bit of research online I found that there is no way to get seconds in `UIDatePicker` and I had to write my own `UIPickerView` from scratch.

So my question is, is there sample code for such i.e. someone wrote a `CustomUIPickerView` for hours, min and secs that I can incorporate in my project? `UIDatePicker` has a nice overlay of Hours & Mins text that stays put while the user rotate the dials. It would be nice if someone added that in their custom picker too. I prefer not to write a custom `UIPickerView` from scratch if I don't have to. Thank you.

Comment: use uiPickerView with 3 components with each having array. HourArray from (1 to 12). MinutesArray with ( 1 to 60). secondsArray ( 1 to 60)

Comment: @safecase. I understand technically how it needs to be done. All I am asking is if someone would like to share this piece of code with me instead of I writing it from scratch

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - please refrain from using "us". You don't speak for the whole iOS development community here. There are a lot of good developers that happily share knowledge and code. If I end up writing the code, I will share it here with the rest of the community and anyone that may be interested in future and reads my post

Comment: I said "us" because Stack Overflow has a pretty clear purpose, and requesting code is not it (if somebody has that code and wants to share it, there are a lot of searchable ways to do it). "We" are here with that premise.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Alrighty folks, here is the code to get hours/mins/secs in your `UIPickerView`. You can add 3 labels an strategically place them on the picker. I have attached a picture as well.

[image]

In your header .h file put this

```
@interface v1AddTableViewController : UITableViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;    
    NSMutableArray *hoursArray;
    NSMutableArray *minsArray;
    NSMutableArray *secsArray;
    
    NSTimeInterval interval;
    
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *hoursArray;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *minsArray;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *secsArray;
```

in your .m file put this

```
@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize hoursArray;
@synthesize minsArray;
@synthesize secsArray;
@synthesize interval;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    
    //initialize arrays
    hoursArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    minsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    secsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *strVal = [[NSString alloc] init];
    
    for(int i=0; i<61; i++)
    {
        strVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        
        //NSLog(@"strVal: %@", strVal);
        
        //Create array with 0-12 hours
        if (i < 13)
        {
            [hoursArray addObject:strVal];
        }
        
        //create arrays with 0-60 secs/mins
        [minsArray addObject:strVal];
        [secsArray addObject:strVal];
    }
    
    
    NSLog(@"[hoursArray count]: %d", [hoursArray count]);
    NSLog(@"[minsArray count]: %d", [minsArray count]);
    NSLog(@"[secsArray count]: %d", [secsArray count]);
    
}


//Method to define how many columns/dials to show
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}


// Method to define the numberOfRows in a component using the array.
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent :(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    if (component==0)
    {
        return [hoursArray count];
    }
    else if (component==1)
    {
        return [minsArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [secsArray count];
    }
    
}


// Method to show the title of row for a component.
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    
    switch (component) 
    {
        case 0:
            return [hoursArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [minsArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [secsArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;    
    }
    return nil;
}


-(IBAction)calculateTimeFromPicker
{
    
    NSString *hoursStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[hoursArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    
    NSString *minsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[minsArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    
    NSString *secsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[secsArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]]];
    
    int hoursInt = [hoursStr intValue];
    int minsInt = [minsStr intValue];
    int secsInt = [secsStr intValue];
    
    
    interval = secsInt + (minsInt*60) + (hoursInt*3600);
    
    NSLog(@"hours: %d ... mins: %d .... sec: %d .... interval: %f", hoursInt, minsInt, secsInt, interval);
    
    NSString *totalTimeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",interval];

}
```

Comment: How can we display "Hours", "Min", "Sec" in picker?

Comment: This got to be one of the most terrible way of doing things... Why would you want to pre-allocate all strings !!?? it also doesn't set the required labels to display "hour" , "min", "secs" as shown on the screen capture

Answer (score 32):

Unlike the accepted solution above, I came up with something a little less terrible. Definitely not perfect, but it has the desired effect (I've only tested in iOS 7 on iPhone, only works in portrait as written). Edits to make better are welcome. Relevant display code below:

```
// assumes you conform to UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource in your .h
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // assumes global UIPickerView declared. Move the frame to wherever you want it
    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;

    UILabel *hourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, picker.frame.size.height / 2 - 15, 75, 30)];
    hourLabel.text = @"hour";
    [picker addSubview:hourLabel];

    UILabel *minsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42 + (picker.frame.size.width / 3), picker.frame.size.height / 2 - 15, 75, 30)];
    minsLabel.text = @"min";
    [picker addSubview:minsLabel];

    UILabel *secsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42 + ((picker.frame.size.width / 3) * 2), picker.frame.size.height / 2 - 15, 75, 30)];
    secsLabel.text = @"sec";
    [picker addSubview:secsLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        return 24;

    return 60;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 30;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *columnView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/3 - 35, 30)];
    columnView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (long) row];
    columnView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    return columnView;
}
```

And the result:

[image: H/M/S Picker]

Comment: Have you tried this with Auto Layout? I'm wondering how it would account for device rotation, different screen sizes, etc. Nice work!

Comment: I have not. As it's written now, it's pretty much just for iPhone portrait view, so there's definitely some limitations.

Comment: Looks very pretty. Could this possibly be packaged and shared?

Comment: I would, but I'm trying to work out the kinks of getting it to look right in landscape mode. I've got it down when using the picker as an `inputView` of a `UITextField` (so the phone handles updating the frame) but not as a standalone view. I'm definitely not the best when it comes to handling orientation changes.

Comment: This should definitely be above the top answer, 32 for that is ridiculous! I think it would be better to use autolayout though as Rod suggests, you could just use the multiplier and center attributes then. Nice work though!

Comment: settings it to 2 columns instead of 3 messes it out obviously because x y numbers are fixed, is there a simple calculation for two columns ? i cant figure.

Comment: @Osa The question was specifically about a date picker with hours, mins, and seconds. If you have a new question, please use the appropriate action. Include a link to this question in your new question for reference.

Comment: i was only trying to make it minutes and seconds :-)

Answer (score 8):

swift implementation

```
class TimePickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var hour:Int = 0
    var minute:Int = 0


    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.setup()
    }

    required internal init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        /*let height = CGFloat(20)
        let offsetX = self.frame.size.width / 3
        let offsetY = self.frame.size.height/2 - height/2
        let marginX = CGFloat(42)
        let width = offsetX - marginX

        let hourLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(marginX, offsetY, width, height))
        hourLabel.text = "hour"
        self.addSubview(hourLabel)

        let minsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(marginX + offsetX, offsetY, width, height))
        minsLabel.text = "min"
        self.addSubview(minsLabel)*/
    }

    func getDate() -> NSDate{
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(String(format: "%02d", self.hour) + ":" + String(format: "%02d", self.minute))
        return date!
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch component {
        case 0:
            self.hour = row
        case 1:
            self.minute = row
        default:
            println("No component with number \(component)")
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return 24
        }

        return 60
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
        if (view != nil) {
            (view as UILabel).text = String(format:"%02lu", row)
            return view
        }
        let columnView = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(35, 0, self.frame.size.width/3 - 35, 30))
        columnView.text = String(format:"%02lu", row)
        columnView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        return columnView
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

I did not like the answers that didn't rely on adding `UILabel` as subviews to `UIPickerView`, because hardcoding the frames will break if iOS decides to change the appearance someday.

A simple trick is to have the hour/min/sec labels as **components with 1 row**.

The hour/min/sec labels will be further from their values, but that's okay. Most users will not even notice that. See for yourself:

[image]

Comment: In this case hour, min and sec components are scrolling as well. Is this possible to prevent?

Comment: This is an easy and simple implementation that shouldn't break with view updates

Answer (score 4):

I made some slight improvements to @Stonz2's version. There was also an error with the calculation of the y position of the labels.

Here the .h file

```
@interface CustomUIDatePicker : UIPickerView <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property NSInteger hours;
@property NSInteger mins;
@property NSInteger secs;

-(NSInteger) getPickerTimeInMS;
-(void) initialize;

@end
```

And here the .m file with the improvements

```
@implementation CustomUIDatePicker
-(instancetype)init {
 self = [super init];
 [self initialize];
 return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
 self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
 [self initialize];
 return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 [self initialize];
 return self;
}

-(void) initialize {
self.delegate = self;
self.dataSource = self;

int height = 20;
int offsetX = self.frame.size.width / 3;
int offsetY = self.frame.size.height / 2 - height / 2;
int marginX = 42;
int width = offsetX - marginX;

UILabel *hourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, offsetY, width, height)];
hourLabel.text = @"hour";
[self addSubview:hourLabel];

UILabel *minsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX + offsetX, offsetY, width, height)];
minsLabel.text = @"min";
[self addSubview:minsLabel];

UILabel *secsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX + offsetX * 2, offsetY, width, height)];
secsLabel.text = @"sec";
[self addSubview:secsLabel];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (component == 0) {
    self.hours = row;
} else if (component == 1) {
    self.mins = row;
} else if (component == 2) {
    self.secs = row;
}
}

-(NSInteger)getPickerTimeInMS {
return (self.hours * 60 * 60 + self.mins * 60 + self.secs) * 1000;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 3;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if(component == 0)
     return 24;

 return 60;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return 30;
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
if (view != nil) {
    ((UILabel*)view).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", row];
    return view;
}
UILabel *columnView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 0, self.frame.size.width/3 - 35, 30)];
columnView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", row];
columnView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

return columnView;
}

@end
```

Comment: ty! may I ask you if I only want 2 columns (minutes, seconds) what should I change? I tried to edit the code a little but couldn't get the result I wanted

Comment: `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` has to return 2 instead.
and in `initialize` you should only create two subviews. also the offsetX should only be something like `self.frame.size.width / 2;`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use ActionSheetPicker

https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

and utilize the ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.  You can follow the example code in the ActionSheetPicker documents.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution here, you can implement 3 method of UIPickerViewDataSource for UIPickerView

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 5;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return 24;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 3:
            return 1;
            break;
        case 2:
        case 4:
            return 60;
            break;
        default:
            return 1;
            break;
    }
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
            return @":";
            break;
        case 0:
        case 2:
        case 4:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (long) row];
            break;
        default:
            return @"";
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for the "hour/min/sec" overlay. It uses the `pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)` method from the picker view's delegate to update the view's label.

This way, it will work no matter the screen orientation. **It still isn't optimal** but it's quite straightforward.

[image: UIPickerView example]

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = String(row)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if let label = pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: component) as? UILabel {

        if component == 0, row > 1 {
            label.text = String(row) + " hours"
        }
        else if component == 0 {
            label.text = String(row) + " hour"
        }
        else if component == 1 {
            label.text = String(row) + " min"
        }
        else if component == 2 {
            label.text = String(row) + " sec"
        }
    }
}
```

To have the overlay appear when the picker view is displayed, rows must be programmatically selected...

```
func selectPickerViewRows() {

    pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
    pickerView.selectRow(30, inComponent: 2, animated: false)

    pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
    pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 1)
    pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: 30, inComponent: 2)
}
```

Comment: Good answer @nyg but you shouldn't use label.text?.append(" min") as if you select twice the row, you got the word twice. Much better to use label.text = String(row)+" min".. But Thanks works great