# ios UI: how to make the control that used in alarm application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make a "number selector" like in alarm application, which has two field - one for minute, one for second, and I can use finger to slide up/down the number to select one. Is it native UI control or I need to customize myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See UIPickerView.  IOS native control.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer on SO
[pickerview with hours, minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds)

Seems like your problem has already been solved.
It only cost me seconds to google it ;)