# How to load a picker view by a for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I want load my picker by a for loop.From 1 to 999.I loaded manually.

My code is here.How I use a "for loop" for load automaticaly. Thanks

```
- (void)numberWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element;

@synthesize numbers = _numbers;

@synthesize selectedIndex = _selectedIndex;

self.numbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",............@"999" nil];

- (IBAction)selectNumbers:(UIControl *)sender {
[ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select a number !" rows:self.numbers  
initialSelection:self.selectedIndex target:self    
successAction:@selector(numberWasSelected:element:) 
cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];

}

 - (void)numberWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];


self.numberTextField.text = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];

  }
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds/11007461#11007461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 1; i <= 999; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}

self.numbers = array;
```