# Simple resource or example in subclassing UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

I am looking to recreate the 3-column picker view found in the "Clock" app's timer, but I also want to replace the hour and minute labels with minute and second labels. Adding another column would be nice, but from what I've researched so far, this doesn't seem like it's an easy task. I've been struggling to figure this out for at least a week.

I've seen a few answers on SO, as well as elsewhere on the internet, but they all seem like overkill for what I actually want to do. A quick answer would be nice, but a guide or explanation as to how I might be able to do this would be much more appreciated. Apple's documentation for this class doesn't actually tell me what I need to implement in my subclass, nor how I would go about adding columns, changing labels, etc.

Does anyone have any resource, example, or hint as to how I might replicate Apple's clock timer?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "they all seem like overkill"? Which solutions have you read, and why don't they work for you? (This will help us avoid recommending approaches that won't work for your use case.)

Comment: So is this what you are looking for?? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds