# Android: Hour/Minute picker like iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, picker

I've searched on Google and these forums but haven't found what I'm looking for so I'll ask here :)

I'm working on an HTML 5 hybrid app project using the Ionic Framework and I'm looking to implement a type of picker that allows the user to select Hours/Minutes (i.e. [5 hours | 30 minutes]).  What our UX design is calling for is something similar to this:

[UIPickerView that looks like UIDatePicker but with seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds)

Is it possible to implement this in Android using the Picker class (doesn't necessarily have to have scrolling wheels like on iOS)?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ use this example

Comment: Have you tried this plugin? https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Comment: Have you checked using standard android time picker in a dialog fragment? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: - Hermantvc I'll probably try that out as a last resort. Looks like that component it backed by ListAdapters, which need to be configured before usage.  A component from the Picker subclass might be preferred.
- mudasserajaz I'm currently using that plugin in the project but it does not have an option to select something like [5 hours | 30 minutes]
- random I'll look into this one tonight.  I haven't found an example where someone can put [5 hours | 30 minutes] into a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is best time picker ever, you can set format with 24hour and 12hour as well

https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker

Comment: I've seen this solution and it looks good but it doesn't have the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late but to whomsoever it may concern , try mobiscroll it has a really awesome IOS like picker with the option to choose different types like hour, minutes, etc.

Here's the link : http://demo.mobiscroll.com/

Just dig into their opensource code available here: https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll 
And if you have any issues integrating just drop a mail to them they have amazing support.

NOTE: Although for direct integration you need to buy a license.