# UIDatePicker interval of 10 minutes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to set a picker for times with 10 minutes intervals so :
8:00,8:10,8:20 , etc , with the minute interval property :

```
UIDatePicker *timePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/1.5)];
timePick.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeTime;

[timePick addTarget:self action:@selector(dateIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
timePick.minuteInterval=10;
```

What happens is that the times are like this :

```
13:00
14:10
15:20
16:30
```

Now if trying to set the hours interval , cant find a property for this .

Whats wrong with it ?

Comment: The hours and minutes are two separate wheels. You can't make one wheel have a fixed value; there would be no point to it -- nothing to pick.

Comment: Agree with @JoshCaswell. Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i am not sure i understand you, i think that having a times wheel that you can set the intervals in which you pick the times is something that is very trivial, and i saw this in other apps .  Cant you set the picker to have the times like: 8:00 , 8:10. 8:20,8:30,8:40 ?

Comment: I think you'd have to not use a plain `UIDatePicker`, @Curnelious; see the question that Abhinav has linked.

Answer (score 17):

I guess you are referring to the [`minuteInterval` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minuteInterval) which is available from iOS2 and later. See below Apple's documentation.

> The interval at which the date picker should display minutes.
>   You can use this property to set the interval displayed by the minutes >wheel (for example, 15 minutes). The interval value must be evenly divided >into 60; if it is not, the default value is used. The default and minimum values are 1; the maximum value is 30.