# Timepicker with seconds

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and somewhere in my application, I need the user to be able to enter a time in the format HH:mm:ss. So, basically I need a control like this one:

[image: Timepicker with seconds]

By using a custom iOS render, I've been able to remove the AM/PM part from the TimePicker to achieve something like this:

[image]

Here's my renderer code:

```
public class TimePickerSecondsRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
        timePicker.Locale = new NSLocale("CA");

    }
}
```

It's a small step in the right direction I suppose, but I'm really at loss when it comes to adding a third column for the seconds, as well as the labels for each column.

I took a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds) but it doesn't really help me so far.

Did anyone managed to achieve that kind of control with their Xamarin Forms project? Would you mind sharing some pointers?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds

Comment: Yes thanks, I've seen it. I mentioned it in my original post.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I think the general answer (for iOS) is to create a Picker (not a DatePicker) with three columns.  There are lots of samples and discussion on doing this, but many are in Obj-C and will need to be translated

Comment: Right, UIPicker might be the way to go. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got a working implementation. Here's the result:

[image]

<strike>The only downside is that the labels "hr", "min", and "sec" are in their own column. As such, there is a bounce effect if the user tries to interact with them. I'll try to see if I can improve it later.</strike>
Suggestions welcome!

And, of course, the code (if it can be of use to someone):

**The renderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(MyTimePicker), typeof(MyTimePickerRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class MyTimePickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        internal static  IDevice Device;

        internal const int ComponentCount = 6;

        private const int _labelSize = 30;

        private MyTimePicker _myTimePicker;

        public MyTimePickerRenderer()
        {
            // This is dependent on XForms (see Update note)
            Device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

                _myTimePicker = e.NewElement as MyTimePicker;

                var customModelPickerView = new UIPickerView
                    {
                        Model = new MyTimePickerView(_myTimePicker)
                    };

                SelectPickerValue(customModelPickerView, _myTimePicker);
            
                CreatePickerLabels(customModelPickerView);

                Control.InputView = customModelPickerView;
            }
        }

    private void SelectPickerValue(UIPickerView customModelPickerView, MyTimePicker myTimePicker)
    { 
        customModelPickerView.Select(new nint(myTimePicker.SelectedTime.Hours), 0, false);
        customModelPickerView.Select(new nint(myTimePicker.SelectedTime.Minutes), 2, false);
        customModelPickerView.Select(new nint(myTimePicker.SelectedTime.Seconds), 4, false);
    }

    private void CreatePickerLabels(UIPickerView customModelPickerView)
    {
        nfloat verticalPosition = (customModelPickerView.Frame.Size.Height / 2) - (_labelSize / 2);
        nfloat componentWidth = new nfloat(Device.Display.Width / ComponentCount / Device.Display.Scale);

        var hoursLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect(componentWidth, verticalPosition, _labelSize, _labelSize));
        hoursLabel.Text = "hrs";

        var minutesLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect((componentWidth * 3) + (componentWidth / 2), verticalPosition, _labelSize, _labelSize));
        minutesLabel.Text = "mins";

        var secondsLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect((componentWidth * 5) + (componentWidth / 2), verticalPosition, _labelSize, _labelSize));
        secondsLabel.Text = "secs";

        customModelPickerView.AddSubview(hoursLabel);
        customModelPickerView.AddSubview(minutesLabel);
        customModelPickerView.AddSubview(secondsLabel);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedIndex")
        {
            var customModelPickerView = (UIPickerView)Control.InputView;

            SelectPickerValue(customModelPickerView, _myTimePicker);
        }
    }
    
    public class MyTimePickerView : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        private readonly MyTimePicker _myTimePicker;

        public MyTimePickerView(MyTimePicker picker)
        {
            _myTimePicker = picker;
        }

        public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
        {
            return new nint(MyTimePickerRenderer.ComponentCount);
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
            {
                // Hours
                return new nint(24);
            }

            if (component % 2 != 0)
            {
                // Odd components are labels for hrs, mins and secs
                return new nint(1);
            }

            // Minutes & seconds
            return new nint(60);
        }

        public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0)
            {
                return row.ToString();
            }
            else if (component == 1)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (component == 3)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (component == 5)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return row.ToString("00");
        }

        public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            var selectedHours = pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(0);
            var selectedMinutes = pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(2);
            var selectedSeconds = pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(4);

            var time = new TimeSpan((int)selectedHours, (int)selectedMinutes, (int)selectedSeconds);

            _myTimePicker.SelectedTime = time;
        }

        public override nfloat GetComponentWidth(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            var screenWidth = MyTimePickerRenderer.Device.Display.Width;

            var componentWidth = screenWidth /
                MyTimePickerRenderer.ComponentCount /
                MyTimePickerRenderer.Device.Display.Scale;
        
            return new nfloat(componentWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom bindable picker class**

```
public class MyTimePicker : Picker
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedTimeProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<MyTimePicker, TimeSpan>(p => p.SelectedTime, TimeSpan.MinValue, BindingMode.TwoWay,propertyChanged: OnSelectedTimePropertyPropertyChanged);

    public MyTimePicker()
    {
        // Ugly hack since Xamarin Forms' Picker uses only one component internally
        // This is a list of all possible timespan from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59
        for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++)
        {
            for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute ++)
            {
                for (int second = 0; second < 60; second++)
                {
                    Items.Add(string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hour, minute, second));
                }
            }
        }

        base.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (base.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                SelectedTime = TimeSpan.MinValue;
                return;
            }

            int index = 0;
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                if (index == SelectedIndex)
                {
                    SelectedTime = TimeSpan.Parse(item);
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }
        };
    }

    public TimeSpan SelectedTime
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(SelectedTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedTimeProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedTimePropertyPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, TimeSpan value, TimeSpan newValue)
    {
        var picker = (MyTimePicker)bindable;

        var itemMatch = picker.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x == newValue.ToString());
        var index = picker.Items.IndexOf(itemMatch);

        picker.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

**XAML usage**

```
<myControls:MyTimePicker SelectedTime="{Binding SelectedTime}" />
```

Where SelectedTime is your ViewModel property used for binding. Must be of type TimeSpan.

I'm sure it can be improved, so comment away if you have suggestions.

### UPDATE

I've updated the renderer code.

- The "hrs", "mins" and "secs" are now label and no longer columns of their own. That means that the user no longer can interact with them (no more bounce effect)
- I've also fixed a bug where, if the picker value was set from the ViewModel, upon opening the keyboard the selection was still at 00:00:00
- Better support for iPhone Plus resolution

Note that this code is dependent on XForms (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) to get the device screen size, because that's the framework that I'm using for my project, but it can easily be modified.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! I modified your example and created a gist https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/c7137c4ea89ededa99dfee51bfb1de4e

Comment: There was a performance issue, because of items population. In the latest version (link available in the first comment) I use only one dummy Item. Since SelectedTime contains the selected value I just update the dummy item value on OnSelectedTimePropertyPropertyChanged.