# TimeSpan picker in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a picker for a TimeSpan - not a time of day. I've tried using the standard TimePicker control, but can't get it to drop time of day formatting in the picker itself - the output format I can change, but the picker always seems to show AM/PM and start at 12:00 not 0:00

I also tried hacking a control together via three independent Picker controls but that just doesn't feel very right.

Is there a control I'm missing, or may some setting on TimePicker I can't find, to let it choose an amount of time, not a time of day?

Comment: "I also tried hacking a control together via three independent Picker controls but that just doesn't feel very right." That is what i ended up doing too. I guess this is just not too much of a common case to have it's own control - mind you iOS does not have a built in for this either, which i am aware of

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with the same problem lately.
 In my case I needed a picker with 3 columns: hh:mm:ss.
 Based on the example from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931470/timepicker-with-seconds/35954206#35954206)  I managed to solve the problem.
The solution is available on [github](https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/c7137c4ea89ededa99dfee51bfb1de4e). 
In short, you have to extend Picker and PickerRenderer to add your own functionality. Don't try to use UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer it has a [bug](https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/14f8ae612020daaa3c4b0d2b3e9f2ba9).

Answer (score 0):

if you are into any 3rd party UI components provider you can check out [Telerik's components](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/datetimepicker/datetime-picker-getting-started). They are versatile and fully customizable. At the moment we have a DateTimePicker which can be customized as Date only or Time only picker. We are working on creating TimeSpan picker which will provide the required functionality and customization.