# How to hide or remove minutes in time picker in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement of display only hours in time picker. I have search a lot for hiding minutes in time picker but not luck. Please suggest any idea for removing or hiding minutes in time picker. Thank you advance.

Comment: just use a regular picker with a list of hours

Comment: We can use that but user not feel like when user select time in time picker.

Comment: Check this thread to get some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931470/timepicker-with-seconds