# Want to replicate a control with two picker

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making a Xamarin.Forms app from an older Xamarin app, and I need to implement a feature that was available in the older version, I looked for the past 3 hours and I can't seem to find any solution.

How could I code this control : http://imgur.com/a/9MHnY ?

I figured i could do a custom picker but I can't find any example online.

Comment: Please provide some code, like how do you code it in the older xamarin version?

Comment: I dont have access to the older code, just the compiled IOS application.

Comment: There's a few very similar approaches in this post that might give you some ideas, though they aren't written in C# / Xamarin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds

However, there is a swift example on that page that might be fairly close to an approach you can use. (Swift being a little more similar to C# in structure than obj-c). It would help if you can updated your question to include a snippet of your sourcecode of what you've tried so far.

Comment: This standard controls sample for Xamarin shows some options that might also be similar to what you need: https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/StandardControls

In particular the "Custom Picker with multiple components" example looks the most similar to your screenshot; perhaps you could put a similar control inside of a Popover for the full effect.