# UIDatePicker as Countdown timer with seconds (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uidatepicker, seconds

So, apple updated the timer app in IOS 11, and one of the most useful things they've done is add a seconds column in the countdown timer, like this:
[countdown timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLK7I.jpg)

I am building an app for personal use and need to use the timer, but for intervals smaller than a minute, but on xcode I can't use the same date picker that Apple used.
Is there a way to build one or to make the UIDatePicker look like that?

Note: I don't understand Objective-C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPickerView that looks like UIDatePicker but with seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10999575/7207883

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) that helps you configure a UIDatePicker-like interface but with custom values to pick from.