# UIDatePicker with date, hours, minutes AND seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an Objective-C project and I am looking for a custom UIPickerView that can select date, hours, minutes AND seconds. Has anyone ever used a similar class ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIPickerView that looks like UIDatePicker but with seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999575/uipickerview-that-looks-like-uidatepicker-but-with-seconds)

Comment: I cannont find UI able to select both date and time WITH seconds.

Comment: One option: use a `UIDatePicker` with date & time, and then show a standard `UIPickerView` with the seconds aligned to the right.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please ?