# Creating Second Delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a second UIPickerView delegate so I can control them individually instead of using if blocks. Below is an example I put together, I'm unsure of how to connect the second UIPickerView outlet to the second UIPickerView delegate (assuming that is all I am missing).

```
import UIKit

protocol secondDelegate {
    func secondPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    func secondNumberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
}

protocol secondDelegateDataSource {
    func secondPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, secondDelegate, secondDelegateDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        p1.delegate = self
        p1.dataSource = self
        p2.delegate = self
        p2.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var p2: UIPickerView!

    var delegate2: secondDelegate?
    var dataSource2: secondDelegateDataSource?

    let picker1 = ["1","3","5"]
    let picker2 = ["2","4","6"]

    // first picker
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return picker1.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return picker1[row]
    }

    // second picker
    func secondNumberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func secondPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return picker2.count
    }

    func secondPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return picker2[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the problem: you are saying the *words* "second delegate", but in *fact* you still have just one delegate — the view controller.

That's your mistake. Make your deeds match your words. Get all the delegate code *out* of the view controller. Instead, give your view controller two helper objects — the two picker delegates. Route the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of the two pickers correctly, one to each delegate. Now the messages are coming and going to completely separate places, and you will not have any single bottleneck with `if` clauses everywhere as you do now.

Here's a simplified example where the two helpers are instance of one class — naturally, nothing requires that you do it that way:

```
class Helper: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    let data: [String]
    init(data: [String]) {
        self.data = data
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        data[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(data[row])
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var p2: UIPickerView!
    let helper1 = Helper(data:["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"])
    let helper2 = Helper(data:["Harpo", "Chico", "Groucho"])
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        p1.delegate = helper1
        p1.dataSource = helper1
        p2.delegate = helper2
        p2.dataSource = helper2
    }
}
```

If the two picker views do very different kinds of thing, then you would want *two separate* Helper classes, each of which acts as a picker view delegate in its own way. Again, the goal here is to avoid having to examine the `pickerView` in the datasource and delegate methods and decide with an if clause what to do; each Helper type would do just one thing.